# Xamarin forms iOS app stops debugging after app installation and launch without any error message

Tags: xcode, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I've been working with an app for quite some time now and yesterday the app all of a sudden just started dying after compilation without any error message whatsoever.

I did some changes in a listview, but later reverted them to see if that had anything to do with it, which it didnt.

Now i have tried lots of things to try to solve this, deleted bin and obj folders, clean, rebuild, closed visual studio, restarted the computer etc without any success.

Yesterday i updated my xamarin enviroment, xcode, mac and also xamarin.forms to 3.2 to see if that would automatically fix the problem for me but the issue still remains.

Any idea what i can try next in order to solve this and is there a way where i will be able to get more information why it dies?

Also i find that sometimes i have some issues with my xamarin.forms references in my iOS custom renderer code, it normally disappears if i rebuild/clean etc, but maybe it is sign of something that is wrong?

[image]

Any help, guidance, advice is very appreciated. Tried solving this for hours now..

Comment: Did it work fine before yesterday?

Comment: Yes it did. After some small code adjustment it just stopped working

Answer (score 0):

If you have already deleted the bin/obj folders and tried to rebuild (note also restart Visual Studio, sometimes restarting the IDE also works).

Then, check if the Xamarin.Forms versions are all the same, this is a must.

After that, try this:

1. Manage NuGet Packages for Solution
2. Remove Xamarin.Forms
3. Reinstall Xamarin.Forms

If that does not work. Try to delete all the packages folder, and restore them again.